# Why is this sentence wrong?

Tags: sentence, present-perfect

> In their stories, originally published in the eighteenth century, the Brothers Grimm **have** embraced a number of themes that have never vanished from life, despite modern advances in science and technology.

I got this question right by removing the **have**. My reasoning was because we know the time in the past that this happened.

Since I just want to make sure, is there any other reason why the **have** is incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: The stories were published in the 19th century.

Comment: "Have embraced" implies that they might even be alive and embracing themes today. "Embraced" is clearly in the past.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham I thought the primary purpose of Present Perfect for an unknown time in the past right? Not just an action continuing up to the present. What if we had a sentence where no time reference was provided? Is it possible to use the Present Perfect then?

Comment: If there were no time reference, and I didn't know who the Brothers Grimm were, using present perfect would definitely sound like they are alive now. "In their stories, the Jones Sisters have embraced a number of themes..."

Comment: No, when you say eighteenth century, it means the 1700s

Comment: @Asker123 No, the other way around. 19th century = 1800s (because the 1st century = Year 1-100).

Comment: There was nothing wrong with 'have embraced'. From the internet: 'Beethoven has composed one of his saddest themes ...' / 'By modeling it upon the Eroica Variations Beethoven has demonstrated how ...' // 'Barely two weeks after arriving, and having impressed Mozart so much he agrees to take him on as a pupil, Beethoven has to return to Bonn...' // '10 Jan 2015 - Why Beethoven has got cardiologists' hearts racing.'  Tenses are not restricted in usage to the obvious time references.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not so much that _have_ by itself, but when combined with “themes that have never vanished from life, despite modern advances in science and technology”, the present perfect becomes very odd-sounding. Similarly, there’s nothing wrong with “He has given his mother a grandfather clock”, but “He has given his mother a grandfather clock which has never needed winding” is out of sync, somehow.

Comment: @Janus That doesn't make the 'have' wrong. And OP focuses largely on the tense used. The sentence _is_ clumsy, unwieldy. 'In their stories, originally published in the eighteenth century, the Brothers Grimm have embraced a number of enduring themes – themes that have not vanished from life, despite modern advances in science and technology.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Even with the rewrite, that present perfect is still jarring to me. Present tense would work, past tense would work … but for some reason, perfect just doesn’t work here. At least not for me. If I were proofreading, I would have changed it too. What annoys me is that I cannot for the life of me figure out _why_ it jars so.

Comment: @Janus My rewrite still _does_ use the present perfect in two of its roles, the 'familiar, time doesn't separate us really' role ('have embraced'; 'are embracing' fulfils this role even better; the authors are still present in their works)  – and the 'from then to the present moment' role (have not vanished ...). If you prefer it, 'Though publishing their stories as far back as the eighteenth century, the Brothers Grimm have embraced a number of enduring themes. These are themes that have not vanished from life, despite modern advances in science and technology.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, it’s the first of those two that jars—I suspect, somehow, because of the added presence of the second one. Your second rewrite, separating the sentences entirely, fixes it. Doesn’t jar there. Utterly bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Brothers Grimm had first published their book just shortly before this sentence was written, the sentence could be using a "hot news perfect".  However, the reference to the eighteenth century tells us that the perspective of the writer is from long after the Brothers Grimm did their work, so the first "have" sounds wrong.

Comment: It's a common enough usage, pragmatically invoking immediacy / familiarity. As in the first two 'Beethoven' quotes above. Stylistically, the temporal parenthesis might be preferred as a preceding sentence, to avoid incongruity.

Answer (score 1):

The present perfect is used in more than one way (Fenn, below, gives four usages ignoring subdivisions). There is the more 'normal', '*completed* (or practiced over a period)  at some time in the past', usage

> these themes have [not] disappeared

but there is also the 'familiar, time doesn't separate us really' role

> 'By modeling it upon the Eroica Variations Beethoven has demonstrated
>   how ...'
>
> cf 'In modeling it upon the Eroica Variations Beethoven is
>   demonstrating how ...'

[first variant from [Beethoven: The Emergence and Evolution of Beethoven's Heroic Style_Michael Broyles](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oRiPOkaMnAAC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=%27By+modeling+it+upon+the+Eroica+Variations+Beethoven+has+demonstrated+%3E+how+...%27&source=bl&ots=TAn8EwqkMb&sig=ARqCdp_X-gHK5DdHxJCuiaDeiJE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SOmDVaT8OOHd7gaDqYKYCQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q='By%20modeling%20it%20upon%20the%20Eroica%20Variations%20Beethoven%20has%20demonstrated%20%3E%20how%20...'&f=false)]

The term 'hot news perfect' is rather disingenuous, as the 'time doesn't really separate us' notion rather than 'in the last few years' is the controlling factor for this usage. [See [A Semantic and Pragmatic Examination of the English Perfect_Peter Fenn](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1jpNgJhjJF4C&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=hot+news+perfect&source=bl&ots=GgeHf58mLm&sig=GreLQ0f8VEQKvg2iOQBtAhrgR1c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MO6DVayOJKKy7QaEx6agAg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=hot%20news%20perfect&f=false), where Fenn refines McCawley's ideas. He suggests the term 'rhematic' for this usage.]

What seems to be the source of discordance here is the pairing of the different usages in the same sentence.

Answer (score -2):

"... have embraced" is the [present perfect tense](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/present-perfect-simple).

"... embraced" is the [simple past tense](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/simpas-pasper).

Also related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40284/switching-from-past-simple-to-present-perfect-in-consecutive-sentences

Answer (score -2):

The present perfect tense is not used to describe actions that took place very long time ago. We say, "Paper was invented by the Chinese." The invention of paper was thousands of years ago. So the use of the present perfect tense "has been invented" here would be incorrect

Comment: This is so broad-brush as to be untrue. For instance, '... Shakespeare has described the brutal mind of Caliban in contact with the pure and original forms of nature' (www.shakespeare-online.com/...).

Comment: *Since 1066 the English language **has** never **been** the same*. (Not the best example, but illustrative I think)

Comment: Abdrabu would be correct if he wrote "the present perfect tense is not used to describe not continuous finished actions in the past", for which past simple must be used except if it is explicit the action had been done before some other action in the past, in which case past perfect is used.